# Simple connected space

Tags: connectedness

I was wondering how to show that $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}^+$ is simple connected (every closed arc is continuously reducible to a dot).

The problem is more how can one write such paths in such space.

Can someone help ?

Comment: A path in this space is described by a path in $\mathbb C$ and a path in $\mathbb R^+$. Their carthesian product is a path in $\mathbb C \times \mathbb R^+$...

Comment: Ok, I've got the point. Thank you !

Comment: Happy to help. Is your question still open or should I post this as an answer?

Comment: I've found your comment complementary to Seirios' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R}^+$ is [star-convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain). Therefore, it is sufficient to notice that any star-convex set is simply connected (see for example this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315631/star-convex-set-is-simply-connected)).

Comment: isn't it convex?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But it is not more complicated to use star-convexity instead of convexity.